# Can I use 12V voltage regulator and a variable 0 to 30V DC power supply to control my 12V DC motor speed?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-motor, speed

I've got a 12V DC motor with:

- Output power: 3.4 watts
- Rated speed : 170 RPM
- Rated current: 0.9A

Currently I have a variable voltage DC power supply which can vary the voltage from the DC power supply from 0 to 30V and an LM7812 voltage regulator.

Can I slow down the motor speed by decreasing the voltage from the DC power supply? I am still unsure what speed is suitable for my motor to rotate in my final year project.

Beside that, there is a lot of things that confuse me and I need some justification.

1. Some people say if I use the 12V L7912CV voltage regulator in my circuit, the current that passes through the voltage regulator is not high enough to activate my DC motor. This is the link of the data sheet [L7912CV](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/88595/STMICROELECTRONICS/L7912CV.html).
2. Some people say if I use a resistor to control my motor speed, the resistor will easily get burned up.
3. The goal of the DC motor is to rotate a disc which is in direct contact with a flat surface so there is friction between them. So in an ideal case, if I buy a 12V power supply and directly connect to the motor, due to the friction and the load, the rated rotating speed will decrease and is suitable for my project. So in my circuit board do I need to buy any other stuff beside a 12V power supply?

Comment: I would feel pretty bad for any 7812 with 30V input that's having more than a couple of mA drawn from it...

Comment: The L7912CV is a _negative_ voltage regulator - you would use it if you wanted a -12 volt supply.  It is not a possible replacement for the 7812 positive regulator.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was **abandoned over five years ago**

Answer (score 2):

[image: pwm]
<sub>(source: [robotroom.com](http://www.robotroom.com/PWM/MotorSpeedControlSchematic.gif))</sub>

Here is a simple example of how to drive DC motor with Transistor and PWN.
The diode is to protect the circuit while the motor is free spinning and to stop fail gating the transistor.
The resistor is protection for the pulse generator i.e. micro controller or 555 chip or the many other ways to make PWN signal.

Comment: The idea of using PWM in this is right, but implementation is *all wrong*.  Don't use a bipolar transistor, use an N channel MOSFET.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the voltage regulator is to *regulate* voltage. If you drive it with over 12V, the output on the regulator is just going to be 12V. Plus, it's going to get very hot supplying 1A. All the regulator will do in this case is act as a limiter, and also a fire hazard.

Why do you need the regulator at all? If this is just for testing, you can just connect the motor directly to the 0-30V supply. Just don't increase it above 12V if that's the maximum motor voltage.

FYI - most small motor applications use a transistor (one-way) or h-bridge (bidirectional) controlled by a PWM channel on a microcontroller or a dedicated PWM controller IC. If you need variable speed control in your final project, this is how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your advised.I put a voltage regulator is just to ensure if i mistakenly turn the knob more than 12v the motor is still safe. For my project i actually just need one constant speed for my motor during the operation but the actual rotating speed that suitable for my project i still cant determined yet since there is a friction and load applied on it.If  without voltage regulator, let say if i reduce the voltage supply by just turning the power supply  from 12v to 1v to determine the speed of the motor needed for my project,can i just directly connect the power supply to the motor ?

Comment: I am still of the opinion that a regulator will be more harm than help in this situation. Just don't turn the dial on the PSU past 12V. Most benchtop supplies also have a currently limiter - enable that and set it to above your maximum motor current. It will reduce or switch off the voltage if the current goes too high. Now, you mention speed control - how critical is accurate speed control to your application?

Comment: Need speed feedback and a closed loop PID control to deal with changes in load and friction while still keeping the desired rotation speed

Comment: Most (decent) motors will tolerate some over-voltage as long as you keep within certain bounds - we worked on a product driving 12v motors at 24v to get the thing moving quickly, so a brief hit of over-voltage, and it never caused problems. Ironically, the motors died when people left them running very slowly (low voltage) because the stators glazed over, we ended up sticking in a daily routine that span the motors full-speed a couple of times to clear it! Running your motor above its rated voltage/current _constantly_ will damage it, but otherwise you should be fine.

Comment: @KyranF: if the load is dynamic, of course that's pretty much the only option. However, it may be that the load is static and just currently unknown, and large error margin for speed is permissible. In that case, PID would probably be overkill. Unforunately, user39706 hasn't provided us with much information about what they're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for every advised especially @freyyr.Really appreciate it.My final year project is design a coin sorter machine in a bigger scale.It is similar to this utube link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LzRPiux50c&index=64&list=PLMNWnjKsLTSTqkzDWHU_Xt7VhFq7c4Q1f.   My concern is because the motor that i bought the rated speed is 175rpm. It might be to fast to turn the rotating disc.So i'm searching any best advice in slowing down the motor with the easier and safe way.

Comment: @freyyr well, the original poster said this: " For my project i actually just need one constant speed for my motor during the operation but the actual rotating speed that suitable for my project i still cant determined yet since there is a friction and load applied on it" Which is why I suggested that.

Comment: @user39706: as much as I love electronic solutions to problems, sometimes they're overkill and a simple mechanical solution will do the job. In this case, why not just gear down the motor? If the torque is not too high you can do it with two differently-sized spindles and a rubber belt.

Comment: @user39706 think about using an "optical encoder" style setup. put a little optical sensor (IR LED + Receiver in one package) and put black lines all around the disc, or even just 4 at exactly 90 degrees difference. Then your controller can just count how fast the disc is spinning, and slowly reduce/increase voltage (via PWM into a single H-bridge driving circuit) until you reach the required speed. That is as simple as i can suggest without doing more crazy power supply adjustments

Comment: @freyyr because everything is already mounted,so electronic solution to problem might be a more convenient way to solve it.

Comment: @user39706: In that case, simply apply a lower voltage to the motor. This doesn't sound like an application where you need closed-loop control, as exact speed is not critical (you just need a ballpark). This will work provided that the motor can create enough torque to spin the shaft at low speed - if not, you'll need to add some gearing.

Comment: @freyyr So if is ok if  i just directly connect my variable power supply to the motor and start reducing the voltage by turning my knob start from 12v and determine how much voltage is suit for me between 12v to 0v when the rotating disc is operating with load and friction?

Comment: @user39706: exactly.

Comment: @KyranF.I'm very bad in electronic stuff.So a controller such as PWm will be a big challenged for me @@.

Comment: 2 more question.Sorry about that.The rated current for my motor is 0.9A. So if is ok if the current of the  power supply provided is less than or more that the rated value. Beside that,i saw at internet that more current will be drawn to the motor if the motor load increased.So if the current drawn by the motor exceed 0.9A,will it burn the motor?

Comment: @user39706: the power supply maximum current must be at _least_ 0.9A, preferrably more to account for inrush starting current. Most benchtop supplies should manage this without trouble. As for your second question - 0.9A is the maximum rated current at full load condition (when the motor is producing maximum rated torque). If the load torque exceeds the maximum, the current will increase beyond 0.9A and the motor will also likely bog down. You should avoid exceeding the maximum current, however, for short amounts of time (no more than a few seconds) small amounts of overcurrent is fine.

Comment: So i guess buying a 0.9A current limiter will solve my second problem?

Comment: The motor _will_ consume more than 0.9A on startup as it takes time to generate back EMF in the armature. Don't worry about current limiting, especially since your benchtop supply is likely already protected. If, despite this, you're still concerned, toss in a 3A slow blow fuse.

Comment: @freyyr electronic shop that nearby house is selling a 12v ,1A dc motor.will it be safe for me to use since the rated current is 0.9A?

Comment: @user39706 - what? I thought you already had a motor? The 0.9A was quoted by you in your original question about a motor you already have. It has no bearing to a new motor with a 1A rated current.

Comment: @freyyr Sorry mistype. Electronic shop that nearby house is selling a 12v ,1A dc power supply .Will it be safe for me to use for my motor since the rated current is 0.9A?Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user39706: I thought you said you already had 0-30V bench top supply?

Comment: @freyyr yeap. The 0 - 30 v bench top supply is actually  borrowed from  robotic engineering friend.Once i know the voltage that is suitable me for my project by using that bench top supply.I might need to buy a fixed voltage supply such as battery or dc supply.

Comment: If you have to use a fixed supply, implement a PWM circuit as JMaher suggests. The 1A supply may work for you provided you don't run the motor flat out. If you need to run it flat out, you'll want a bigger supply. I'd get a 2A supply just in case.